# Finding a value in one list which corresponds to another value in a different list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a set of data where I am required to find the value of a peak and find its corresponding value in another list. The list with the peak value in it contains 1 element. The list of x values in the other list contains multiple. how do i find the x value corresponding to the y value i have found.

I want to find which value in x, the value in yvals corresponds to.

My code so far is as follows:

```
#initial data
x=data[:,0]
y=data[:,1]

# loop to find the data points of the peak
ypeak=[]
for i in range(0, len(y)-1) :
    if y[i]> 50:
        ypeak.append(y[i])
print('ypeak = {}'.format(ypeak))

# loop to find the max value of the peak
yvals=[]
for j in range(0, len(ypeak)-1):
    if ypeak[j-1] < ypeak[j] and ypeak[j] > ypeak[j+1]:
        yvals.append(ypeak[j])
print('yvals = {}'.format(yvals))
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code you've posted in the question, does it not output your expect result, or do you get any errors?

Comment: what is `data`, a list of integers, or tuples? I tried your code with `data` as a list of random integers, I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple` on line 2. could you provide an example of what the `data` list contains?

Comment: i have managed to find a solution to the problem but thank you for trying to solve it!

Comment: Great to hear you solved it @James H, cheers!